# how describe something that happens without you realizing it, but it is a nice/good thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

It could be be unwittingly, but the word has a negative connotation as it may be related to ignorance. I'm looking for a more positive concept.

Comment: I seem to remember the phrase 'unmarked blessing', but there seem very few instances of it on the internet. Ditto for 'unrecognised blessing / boon'. A 'hidden benefit' is a near-hypernym.

Comment: I like the submitted answer serendipitous however if it seems a bit too beyond 4 rth grade vocabulary you might try something like a "side benefit" or, for a larger 'unexpected blessing', a 'windfall'

Answer (score 2):

Me thinks ... **serendipity**. A happenstance of luck.

An example:  'I was thinking of new ways to engage with my audience and with a bit of serendipity and inspiration the cake was born.'

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/serendipity